# pc turns on but display nothing

Tags: display, power-supply, power

I turn on my pc all the fans and leds working but no Beep and nothing on the display then on turn it off and on again it works fine with NO problem then  I turn it off and the same scenario again and again 
I have no idea what is this and what to do

Comment: And now all the punctuation keys have fallen off your keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with two of the mainboard capacitors near PCI-E slot . I changed them with two identical one ,and it solved the problem.

-Posting this in case anyone came here for the solution